# rivz/ogre crash after update

Tags: rviz, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with the diamondback ROS release.  I just upgraded my installation and now I can't seem to run rviz any more.  I was running it fine like 30 minutes ago before I decided to update my system.  I attached the error.  I tried searching on answers but I didn't see anything immediately relevant.

```
andrewha@andrewha-G73s:~$ rosrun rviz rviz 

Failed to initialize Ogre: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library Plugin_CgProgramManager.  System Error: Plugin_CgProgramManager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in DynLib::load at /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-visualization-common-1.4.1/debian/ros-diamondback-visualization-common/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 91)

[ERROR] [1310250509.390105644]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library Plugin_CgProgramManager.  System Error: Plugin_CgProgramManager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in DynLib::load at /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-visualization-common-1.4.1/debian/ros-diamondback-visualization-common/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 91)

andrewha@andrewha-G73s:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10545/rivz/ogre-crash-after-update/) by [andrew-unit](https://answers.ros.org/users/407/andrew-unit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-07-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-13**:
I'm having the same issue. Are you using the deb packages, or building independantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, it looks like something went wrong in how the debian packages were built for visualization_common in the latest diamondback release. I filed a ticket on this here, https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5059, and the stack maintainer is looking into things. Until this is resolved, the solution seems to be to build visualization_common from source. Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-07-14**:
it has been resolved.  the nvidia cg packages failed silently during the build.  we have rebuilt and reployed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This post helped me.  I basically did a make wipe in ogre and rebuilt ogre and ogre_tools, and now I can run rviz again.

http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/rviz-installation-td766428.html

---

Originally posted by [andrew-unit](https://answers.ros.org/users/407/andrew-unit/) with karma: 283 on 2011-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-13**:
Removing and reinstalling deb packages on the other hand does not work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem today.
rebuild ogre in visualization_stack helps. by building Tarball seems not to work. simply uncomment the downloading lines in the Makefile

---

Originally posted by [dong](https://answers.ros.org/users/818/dong/) with karma: 13 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I upgraded my ROS installation yesterday, and this OGRE bug re-materialized.

My solution: Update my Ubuntu sources.list to packages.ros.org instead of the old code.ros.org.  From the current ROS installation page:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

Apparently the location of the packages has changed recently?  Whereas the code.ros.org repos showed no new packages (after "apt-get update"), the packages.ros.org repos **did**.  I ran a dist-upgrade using the packages.ros.org repos, which pulled down a (new?) version of the visualization libraries.  This eliminated the bug.  YMMV.

---

Originally posted by [Travis Deyle](https://answers.ros.org/users/287/travis-deyle/) with karma: 91 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Travis Deyle](https://answers.ros.org/users/287/travis-deyle/) on 2011-09-02**:
Ha!  Good to know.  Somehow I missed that announcement on ros-users.  Based on my experiences, it would seem that the package repositories are not quite being mirrored at this time.  So everyone should update their apt sources!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-09-02**:
code.ros.org for debian packages is deprecated. See also https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110705.165117.40fb67c6.en.html